# How to open on PC Rasperry IP with port

Tags: raspberry-pi

on my raspberry, I installed "motion" (the one with daemon) for my Pi Camera. However, I set up the Motion with the port 8081. If I open it on the raspberry using localhost:8081 it works but unfortunately with a big delay/lag. Maybe if you find a solution to this would be awesome. But my main problem is that if I want to open the server on my Pc by entering 192.168.xxx.xx:8081, it won't open at all. Using the IP without the port it still works. Maybe you find a solution.

Comment: I use the link that Nemanja sends me and add an image that contain a src with your ip address :
<img src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8081/?action=stream" alt="" width="640" height="480">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lag you encounter on Raspberry pi is because that same raspberry is processing the video input, and now you want to add processing of showing you that stream, after all, it is raspberry, no big deal there.

The Motion config file (*/etc/motion/motion.conf*) haves a setting named "Stream_localhost" by default it is set to **ON**, make sure you change it to **OFF**.

If you have any other problems I believe this simple instruction will help you.

[How to Make Raspberry Pi Webcam Server and Stream Live Video || Motion + Webcam + Raspberry Pi](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-Raspberry-Pi-Webcam-Server-and-Stream-/)

***EDIT:***
After quick google searching I found out that two more settings **must** be set to off also

```
webcam_localhost off

control_localhost off
```

Comment: Thank you for yoour answer. I already tried this instruction and it works to stream the video to my webserver. However the lag is still there also if I switch stream_localhost off

Comment: Have you tried pining the Motion web server?

Comment: I tried using your idea but it has still lags. It is like the cam only send images that we see and it has still a delay of 2-4 seconds¨

Comment: whar dou you mean with pining?

Comment: $ ping raspberrypi:8081